# R - delete rows according to the value of another row

Tags: r, delete-row

I am quite a beginner in R but thanks to the community of Stackoverflow I am improving!
However, I am stuck with a problem:

I have a dataset with 5 variables:

- id_house represents the id for each household
- id_ind is an id which values 1 for the first individual in the household, 2 for the next, 3 for the third...
- Indicator_tb_men which indicates if the first person has answered to the survey (1 = yes, 0 = no). All the other members of the household take the value 0.

```
id_house    id_ind   indicator_tb_men
1             1       1
1             2       0
2             1       1
3             1       0
3             2       0
3             3       0
4             1       1
5             1       0
```

I would like to delete all members of households where the first individual has not answered the survey.

So it would give:

```
id_house    id_ind   indicator_tb_men
1             1       1
1             2       0
2             1       1
4             1       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` here is one way :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(id_house, id_ind) %>%
  group_by(id_house) %>%
  filter(first(indicator_tb_men) != 0)

#  id_house id_ind indicator_tb_men
#     <int>  <int>            <int>
#1        1      1                1
#2        1      2               NA
#3        2      1                1
#4        4      1                1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id_house = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
id_ind = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), indicator_tb_men = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect! However, i indicated having missing values but they take the value 0... Could you help me once more?

Answer (score 0):

in base we can use nested logic

```
df[df$id_house %in% df$id_house[df$id_ind == 1 & df$indicator_tb_men == 1],]

  id_house id_ind indicator_tb_men
1        1      1                1
2        1      2               NA
3        2      1                1
7        4      1                1
```

Data: Using [Ronak Shah's data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62514957/10442423)

Comment: Thank you but I have at the beginning 42688 rows and I still have them after doing what you suggest... And if I do : `table(ifelse(df$id_ind == 1 & df$indicator_tb_men == 0, 1, 0))` I know there are 63 values that sould be discarded...

Comment: did you overwrite the old df? `df <- df[df$id_house %in% df$id_house[df$id_ind == 1 & df$indicator_tb_men == 1],]`

Comment: I used it once with the old df and once with the new df